# Adding the timestamp to heap dump filename generated from java application running in kubernetes pod

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, heap-dump

I want to add a timestamp after the heap dump filename. It works when I specify the `-XX:HeapDumpPath` option when running the command below:

```
java -Xmx64m  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=outputFilename.$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin -jar app.jar
```

But when this option is set on the Kubernetes service yml file is not working. Below is option defined in the yml file:

```
    env:
        - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: " -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=\"/dumps/heap-dump/demo-heap-dump$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin\""
```

It throws the error below when trying to create heap dump

```
2022-08-09 13:02:15.901 CESTPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/dumps/heap-dump/"demo-heap-dump$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin
2022-08-09 13:00:56.853 CESTUnrecognized option: +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin
```

Thank you for your help.

Best regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to solve this issue. It is not possible to solve it by adding `XX:HeapDumpPath=\"/dumps/heap-dump/demo-heap-dump$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin\""`   in yml because it will not be executed. For this line `$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S)` to be executed it needs to run on the bash terminal.

I removed the line below from the yml file:

```
 - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: " -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=\"/dumps/heap-dump/demo-heap-dump$(date +_%m%d%Y.%H:%M:%S).bin\""
```

Modified the docker file to use bash to execute jar and not the java command like below:

```
FROM repo/jdk8

ADD target/app.jar app.jar

#CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/app.jar" ] 

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps/heap-dump/app-heap-dump$(date +-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).hprof -jar  /app.jar "]

EXPOSE 5147
```

After the modification, I am to store the heap dump with the timestamps attached to the filename of the heap dump.